# Need to declare local functions or variables inside a local table?

Tags: lua

In lua if I have

```
local table={}

table.variableA=1 -- this is local?


local table2=
{
    local variable2=2 -- this is the same that above?
}
```

and when I declare functions inside a local table, they are all locals?

Comment: This is not the correct use of the `local` keyword. Error: `8: unexpected symbol near 'local' `
Any variables (or tables, functions) inside tables are its elements and nothing more.

Comment: but variables inside a local function without local keyword are global...

Comment: Not global and not local - only elements of tables.. Elements have no area of visibility, they only have an index with which they exist inside table.

Comment: and a variable inside a function inside a local table? the function is local because is inside the table, and the variable?

Comment: Same as without table. Variables in functions are local as long as they are declared local, otherwise they are global in the environment function is called in. The fact that function is an element of a table doesn't change anything.

Comment: thanks, I understand now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes, but no.

Functions aren't *local*, they are just values. It's variables that are local or not. For example, imagine this:

```
function foo_global() print 'foo' end
local foo_local = foo_global
```

You have two variables, one global and one local, and they both contain the same function value.

When you store a function into a table, it's neither global nor local, as it's not a variable. The table can be stored in a local variable, but that doesn't really affect the function itself, only where you can access it from.

Inside a table constructor, that is, between curly braces `{` `}` you cannot use the `local` keyword, because it makes no sense there.